# How to disable auto commit for SimpleConsumer kafka 0.8.1

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to disable auto commit for kafka SimpleConsumer. I am using 0.8.1 version.For High level consumer, config options can be set and passed via consumerConfig as follows
kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(this.consumerConfig);

How can I achieve the same for SimpleConsumer? I mainly want to disable auto commit. I tried setting auto commit to false in consumer.properties and restarted kafka server, zookeeper and producer. But, that does not work. I think I need to apply this setting through code, not in consumer.properties.
Can anyone help here?

Here is how my code looks like

```
List<TopicAndPartition> topicAndPartitionList = new ArrayList<>();              
topicAndPartitionList.add(topicAndPartition); 
OffsetFetchResponse offsetFetchResponse = consumer.fetchOffsets(new     OffsetFetchRequest("testGroup", topicAndPartitionList, (short) 0, correlationId,    clientName));

 Map<TopicAndPartition, OffsetMetadataAndError> offsets =     offsetFetchResponse.offsets();   
FetchRequest req = new FetchRequestBuilder() .clientId(clientName)                .addFetch(a_topic, a_partition, offsets.get(topicAndPartition).offset(), 100000)   .build();
 long readOffset = offsets.get(topicAndPartition).offset();  
FetchResponse fetchResponse = consumer.fetch(req);

//Consume messages from fetchResponse


Map<TopicAndPartition, OffsetMetadataAndError > requestInfo = new HashMap<>  (); 
requestInfo.put(topicAndPartition, new OffsetMetadataAndError(readOffset, "metadata", (short)0));
OffsetCommitResponse offsetCommitResponse = consumer.commitOffsets(new         OffsetCommitRequest("testGroup", requestInfo, (short)0, correlationId, clientName));
```

If above code crashes before committing offset, I still get latest offset as result of offsets.get(topicAndPartition).offset() in next run which makes me to think that auto commit of offset happens as code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Using SimpleConsumer just means you want to take care of everything about the message consuming including offset commits, so no auto commit is supported for low-level APIs.

Comment: I added code snippet above. If my app crashes before committing offset, I still get latest offset in next run. So, I think auto commit happens internally if its not explicitly disabled.

Comment: It's because config 'auto.offset.reset' is set to largest by default, which means consumer will reset its offset to the largest offset if no initial offset was stored on Zookeeper(Version 0 always stores to zookeeper)

Comment: Even with multiple runs when commit offset was successful earlier, I see the same behavior. Doesn't commitOffsets writes to zookeeper?

Comment: Yes, it commits offsets to zookeeper. Please check zookeeper znode '/consumers/<group>/offsets/<topic>/<partitionId> to see if offsets had been committed successfully.